# How can I extract the embedded files store in a OneNote 2010 .one file?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

How can I extract files that I have embedded in a OneNote 2010 .one file?  If there is no easy way to do that, is there a way to get a list of all of them in the notebook or section so it is easy to grab them all and dump them to disk?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/how-to-extract-embedded-attachments-from-onenote/040ea140-915a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=5b26f792-075b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Comment: Yeah I knew that was the running answer in some of the forums.  I was hoping that some other SuperUser had figured it out.

Comment: Perhaps if the format's internal details are known or have been reverse engineered someone might have come up with an extraction utility. Quite a niche requirement though so wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: I'm kind of shocked they haven't been.  When files aren't embedded the .one file format seems like all other Office files from 2010, a zip file with a file structure and XML inside.

Comment: So it's ZIP based too like the other OOXML formats? Then what happens to the embedded files? Aren't they accessible when you extract the archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found (OneNote 2010):

1. Select your OneNote page(s)
2. File -> Send -> E-mail Page
3. All of your embedded files will be in a new email as attachments. Now you can extract them from there.

Comment: On Mac this only works for images. PDFs are not added to the mail. :(

Answer (score 0):

In OneNote 2016, it is possible to click in the note when it is open, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy all.

If there is a large number of attachments, it may lag for a few seconds.

Then you can paste into a file explorer window to drop all of the embeds into the folder.